# How to Customize HazardMap?

Tags: ios, ios4, mkmapview, overlay

I have downloaded  sample code from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/HazardMap/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010049 
but it takes everything from some specific file.I want to use that code for Weather displaying purpose anyone has idea about it or how to customize this sample code according to our requirement.Please help i don't have any idea about it.